# Find String Pattern in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sequence

I want to find a pattern in the following string:

```
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTCAANGGGACGGAGCGGGTGCNGTNNCNGGANAGANNCNTCNATNANCNNGAGGAGNNCNNGCGCTTCGACAGCGACGTGGGGGAGTNCNNGGCGGTGACNGAGCTNGGGCGGCCTNNNGNNGAGNNCTGGAACAGCCAGAAGGACNTCCTGGANNNNNNNCNNGNCNNNGTGGACANNNNNTGCAGACACAACTACGGGGNTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

The pattern must contain at least 4 adjacent characters, except 'N'.

For example in this string,

```
NNNNNTTCAANGGGACGG.....
```

I can get "TTCA" "TCAA" "GGGA", "GGAC" , "GACG", "ACGG" ...

I would like to find any possible string that matches the pattern.

Which method is best for this?

I can create an array and read each character.
However, is there any better design and idea for this?

Thank you !

Comment: You might want to take a look at how Java does [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).  There are also oodles of regexp tutorial floating around the web.

Comment: string.replaceAll("N", ""); then just read 4 chars from every position.

Comment: @user1445898 no it can't because character has to be continue for example "AANGG" cannot make continuing words without "N" but if I remove "N" then it will be "AAGG" it's wrong

Comment: @user1445898 the characters must be continuous in the original string.

Comment: oh, then string.split("N") and scan every substring with length>=4

Comment: @kaktusito default regex do not 'intersect' i.e. ".{2}" will match "123" only once. Also regexps are harder to understand so i prefer to avoid them if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `Pattern` and a `Matcher`. Using the `Matcher#find(int index)` you can start matching from a specified index. The given `Pattern` is matched, and the `Matcher` is reset to start from the previous matching position + 1 so no substring is missed.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[A-M|O-Z]{4}").matcher(
            "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTT"
                    + "CAANGGGACGGAGCGGGTGCNGTNNCNGGANAGANNCNTC"
                    + "NATNANCNNGAGGAGNNCNNGCGCTTCGACAGCGACGTGG"
                    + "GGGAGTNCNNGGCGGTGACNGAGCTNGGGCGGCCTNNNGN"
                    + "NGAGNNCTGGAACAGCCAGAAGGACNTCCTGGANNNNNNN"
                    + "CNNGNCNNNGTGGACANNNNNTGCAGACACAACTACGGGG"
                    + "NTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN");

    int index = 0;
    while (m.find(index)) {
        index = m.start() + 1;
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
TTCA
TCAA
GGGA
GGAC
GACG
ACGG
CGGA
GGAG
GAGC
AGCG
GCGG
CGGG
GGGT
GGTG
GTGC
GAGG
AGGA
GGAG
GCGC
CGCT
GCTT
CTTC
TTCG
TCGA
CGAC
GACA
ACAG
CAGC
AGCG
GCGA
CGAC
GACG
ACGT
CGTG
GTGG
TGGG
GGGG
GGGG
GGGA
GGAG
GAGT
GGCG
GCGG
CGGT
GGTG
GTGA
TGAC
GAGC
AGCT
GGGC
GGCG
GCGG
CGGC
GGCC
GCCT
CTGG
TGGA
GGAA
GAAC
AACA
ACAG
CAGC
AGCC
GCCA
CCAG
CAGA
AGAA
GAAG
AAGG
AGGA
GGAC
TCCT
CCTG
CTGG
TGGA
GTGG
TGGA
GGAC
GACA
TGCA
GCAG
CAGA
AGAC
GACA
ACAC
CACA
ACAA
CAAC
AACT
ACTA
CTAC
TACG
ACGG
CGGG
GGGG
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a Java 8 Stream with some filtering, mapping and collecting:

```
String str = "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTCAANGGGACGGAGCGGGTGCNGTNNCNGGANAGANNCNTCNATNANCNNGAGGAGNNCNNGCGCTTCGACAGCGACGTGGGGGAGTNCNNGGCGGTGACNGAGCTNGGGCGGCCTNNNGNNGAGNNCTGGAACAGCCAGAAGGACNTCCTGGANNNNNNNCNNGNCNNNGTGGACANNNNNTGCAGACACAACTACGGGGNTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN";
final char[] src = str.toCharArray();

final int len = 4;
final int ch = 'N';
final List<String> collect =
        IntStream.range(0, str.length() - len)
                .filter(offset -> IntStream
                        .range(offset, offset + len)
                        .noneMatch(i -> src[i] == ch))
                .boxed()
                .map(i -> str.substring(i, i + len))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(collect); // [TTCA, TCAA, GGGA, GGAC, ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my regex-allergic solution. Credits to @Niels Billen for nice source string formatting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String string =  "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTT"
                        + "CAANGGGACGGAGCGGGTGCNGTNNCNGGANAGANNCNTC"
                        + "NATNANCNNGAGGAGNNCNNGCGCTTCGACAGCGACGTGG"
                        + "GGGAGTNCNNGGCGGTGACNGAGCTNGGGCGGCCTNNNGN"
                        + "NGAGNNCTGGAACAGCCAGAAGGACNTCCTGGANNNNNNN"
                        + "CNNGNCNNNGTGGACANNNNNTGCAGACACAACTACGGGG"
                        + "NTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN";

     for (String s: string.split("N")) {
         for (int i = 0 ; i <= s.length() - 4 ; i++) {
             System.out.println(s.substring(i, i + 4));
         }
     }
}
```